# Determining a rolling Moving Average inPython scheduled time event with SQL select statement

Tags: python, sql

I'm using a python script to report, every hour, the rolling 24 hour MA from a price database.

Below I use sched.scheduler to for the initial run and then re-run itself every hour (3600 seconds). My issue is that after 24 hours this begins to report the daily MA as "None" which makes me think the time (either current time or the interval time) being evaluated is calculating at script initiation and not recalculating dynamically each time the scheduled event fires.
I've tried replacing the SQL"now()" variable with a python variable to capture the current time each time the even fires to no avail.

```
def get_daily_ma():
    global get_daily_ma
    cursor.execute("SELECT AVG(price) AS DailyAvg FROM price_log.price WHERE date_time >= (now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)")
    get_daily_ma = cursor.fetchone()
    for row in get_daily_ma:
        print('Daily MA:' + str(row))



import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc):
    try:
        get_daily_ma()           
    except Exception as error:
        if error is not None:
            print('Caught this error: ' + repr(error))
        else:
            print('Connected successfully to database')
        connect()
    s.enter(3600, 1, do_something, (sc,))

s.enter(1, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Current Example Output:

```
Daily MA:706.600501
Daily MA:705.500622
Daily MA:705.633035
Daily MA:705.072559
Daily MA:704.854059
Daily MA:704.022256
Daily MA:703.536127
Daily MA:703.123755
Daily MA:702.689111
Daily MA:702.492884
Daily MA:701.039226
Daily MA:700.661540
Daily MA:698.483458
Daily MA:697.863890
Daily MA:697.453988
Daily MA:697.432582
Daily MA:696.884967
Daily MA:696.159034
Daily MA:696.399219
Daily MA:695.599022
Daily MA:695.254403
Daily MA:695.671413
Daily MA:695.474621
Daily MA:697.200574
Daily MA:None
Daily MA:None
Daily MA:None
Daily MA:None
Daily MA:None
Daily MA:None
```

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: `now()` should be re-evaluated every time the query is run.

Comment: What about the interval?  Should that also evaluate at each time the script runs?

Comment: The expression `now() - interval 24 hour` should be evaluated each time the database is run.  This is using the timeframe of the database at the time the query is run, so I don't see how this could be causing your problem.

Comment: Hi Gordon, You were correct. This turned out to be an issue with when I had my cursor opening and closing.

Comment: Curious, does your data change with each hour?

Comment: Yes. The database is continually being fed new records via another script. Therefore I need to re-evaluate what the last 24 hours of records are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gordon suggested it wasn't the SQL evaluation but wound up being the only other option which was the cursor grabbing the records to be evaluated. I updated it to approximately this which solved the issue by opening and closing the cursor in the loop.

```
def get_daily_ma():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(...)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT AVG(price) AS DailyAvg FROM price_log.price WHERE date_time >= (now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)")
    get_daily_ma = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
    for row in get_daily_ma:
        print('Daily MA:' + str(row))
```

Comment: And it is best practice to always close db objects after each query call otherwise you face such strange side effects as you report.